# Curious spacing while using variables with \newcommand

Tags: renewcommand

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcommand{\cvAnrede}{Herr}
\newcommand{\cvTitel}{Dr.}
\newcommand{\cvVorname}{Max}
\newcommand{\cvNachname}{Mustermann}

\newcommand{\cvSetTitel}[1]
{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\cvTitel}
}

\newcommand{\setName}[1]
{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvAnrede{} \cvSetTitel{\cvTitel} \cvNachname }{\cvVorname }
}

\newcommand{\setCompleteName}[1]
{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvSetTitel{\cvTitel} \cvVorname \cvNachname }{\cvVorname}
}

\newcommand{\cvName}{\setName{\cvSetName}}
\newcommand{\cvFullName}{\setCompleteName{\cvSetName}}

\begin{document}

\ifdefined\cvSetName
\else 
  \def\cvSetName{nachname}
\fi


\cvName \\
Herr Dr. Mustermann


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

What is my mistake? I don't understand why 1. there are spacing and 2. there are different spacing.

Comment: I would assume that the first one has a paragraph indentation, and that it has nothing to do with all of your newcommanding.

Comment: Oh.  You're looking at the spacing after "Dr.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have spurious spaces in your definitions--end of lines count. Hide them with %

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcommand{\cvAnrede}{Herr}
\newcommand{\cvTitel}{Dr.}
\newcommand{\cvVorname}{Max}
\newcommand{\cvNachname}{Mustermann}

\newcommand{\cvSetTitel}[1]
{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\cvTitel}%
}

\newcommand{\setName}[1]
{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvAnrede{} \cvSetTitel{\cvTitel} \cvNachname }{\cvVorname }%
}

\newcommand{\setCompleteName}[1]
{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvSetTitel{\cvTitel} \cvVorname \cvNachname }{\cvVorname}%
}

\newcommand{\cvName}{\setName{\cvSetName}}
\newcommand{\cvFullName}{\setCompleteName{\cvSetName}}

\begin{document}

\ifdefined\cvSetName
\else
  \def\cvSetName{nachname}
\fi



\cvName \\
Herr Dr. Mustermann


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well spotted egreg